# Memory management of interfaces in Delphi

Tags: delphi, memory-management, interface, access-violation

I am struggling to learn delphi and memory management, coming from C#.

The current incarnation of that struggle is that I don't know the right way to dispose of the objects when I am done with them.  From reading and my experiments it seems that if I have an object that is cast as an interface, then my ONLY choice is set the reference to nil.
If I go an call 
FreeAndNil()
I end up getting an access violation, EX:

```
var
  foo: IFoo;
begin
  foo := TFoo.Create();
  FreeandNil(foo);
end;
```

Sure, all I need to do it change that foo:IFoo; to foo:TFoo; and it is happy. OR simply set the pointer to nil, NOT call freeandNil.

```
foo := nil;
```

So, on one level, I don't understand in the least where the AV is.

On a differently level, I want to write the code such that it does not need to know if it is an interface or an object.  I want to be able to write all of my memory management the same exact way, but I can't seem to write a method that can deal with something that is a Class or an interface.  Well, that is not true, I do have something, but it is so ugly I hesitate to post it.

But I guess I should also be asking, what is everyone else doing?  Mentally keeping track of what is an interface and just nil those pointers?  otherwise calling FreeAndNil?

I am going to want to implement things the first time around as a concrete class, but later come back and change that to an interface when I find some way that the code can do  from 2 different ways.  And I am not going to want to go through the code and change how it was dealing with that reference, that is the last thing on my mind at that point.

But for the sake of discussion, the best (almost only) idea I have is this class:

```
interface

type
  TMemory = class(TObject)
  class procedure Free(item: TObject); overload; static;
  class procedure Free<T: IInterface>(item: T); overload; static;
  end;

implementation

uses
  System.SysUtils;

  { TMemory }

class procedure TMemory.Free(item: TObject);
begin
  FreeandNil(item);
end;

class procedure TMemory.Free<T>(item: T);
begin
  //don't do anything, it is up the caller to always nil after calling.
end;
```

Then I can consistently call:

```
TMemory.Free(Thing);
Thing := nil;
```

Test code:

```
procedure TDoSomething.MyWorker;
var
  foo: IFoo;
  fooAsClass: TFoo;
  JustAnObject: TObject;
begin
  foo := TFoo.Create();
  fooAsClass := TFoo.Create();
  JustAnObject := TObject.Create();

  TMemory.Free(foo);
  foo := nil;

  TMemory.Free(fooAsClass);
  fooAsClass := nil;

  TMemory.Free(JustAnObject);
  JustAnObject := nil;
end;
```

runs with no leaks or access violations. (using MadExcept)

But a big thank you to the Delphi community on SO.  You guys have been the best thing out there for learning!

Comment: You don't need to set an interface reference to nil. Just let it go out of scope. For objects you need to start using try finally. Otherwise you will leak.

Comment: This is a simplification.  Most of the code I am dealing with keep a reference to an interface passed to them.  So I am trying to work out my destructor code.

Comment: There's nothing to do in the destructor. The reference goes out of scope and if it's the final reference then the implementing object is destroyed.

Comment: and if you've destroyed it beforehand, RTL's attempt to do so causes an AV.

Comment: Certainly your `TMemory` type serves no purpose other than to increase your confusion

Comment: You are really trying to bend the rules

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for the access violation is that `FreeAndNil` takes an *untyped* parameter, but ***expects*** it to be an object. So the method operates on the object.

```
procedure FreeAndNil(var Obj);
var
  Temp: TObject;
begin
  Temp := TObject(Obj); //Obj must be a TObject otherwise all bets are off
  Pointer(Obj) := nil; //Will throw an AV if memory violation is detected
  Temp.Free; //Will throw an AV if memory violation is detected
end;
```

A memory violation in the above *might* (NB not guaranteed) be detected if you destroy an object that has either been previously destroyed or never created. It's also likely to be detected if `Obj` doesn't reference an object at all but something else (such as an interface, record, Integer because these don't implement `Free` and if they did, it wouldn't be located in the same way as `TObject.Free`).

> On a differently level, I want to write the code such that it does not need to know if it is an interface or an object. I want to be able to write all of my memory management the same exact way.

This is like saying you want to use your car in exactly the same way that you use your shower.
*Ok, maybe the difference is not quite that extreme.* But the point is that interfaces and objects (and for that matter records) use ***different*** memory management paradigms. You ***cannot*** manage their memory in the same way.

- Objects need to be explicitly destroyed. You can use an ownership model, but destruction is still an explicit external action.
- Interfaces are reference counted. The compiler injects code to track the number of fields and variables referencing (looking at) the underlying instance. Typically the object destroys itself when the last reference is released. (There are ways *beyond the scope of this answer* to change this.)

Comment: Actually Pointer(Obj) := nil will do nothing but assign NIL to the parameter. No side effects (and no AV) are possible because of the type cast to a plain pointer. But Temp.Free will most likely cause an AV for interfaces because these do not point to a VMT that contains Destroy.

Comment: @dummzeuch Remember the parameter is _untyped_ meaning you can pass pretty much anything; including a dereferenced object pointer (e.g. in a list structure). If you pass dereferenced **nil** E.g. `P := nil; FreeAndNil(P^);` then that memory violation _will_ be detected and `Pointer(Obj) := nil;` will raise an AV.

Comment: Thank you, things are slowly making more sense.  After years of never cleaning up after myself, it is hard to learn the right frame of mind for it.  But everyone's comments have really helped to put memory management in better perspective.  Had a bit of a light bulb moment and finally tracked down an "Impossible" memory leak.  So things are lookup up.

Answer (score 4):

If we access some object by interface variable, it doesn't always mean that object is destroyed the moment reference counter drops to zero. For example, `TComponent` methods _AddRef and _Release implementations are 'dummy': no reference counting is implemented and TComponent is never destroyed because interface variables are out of scope.

To behave as we expect from 'real' interfaces, all your objects should be descendants from `TInterfacedObject` or you need to implement `_AddRef` / `_Release` yourself.

Yes, there are 2 different approaches to memory management which usually co-exist in a program, but confusion (and AV) arises only when the same object is treated in both ways. If we destroyed object and only then the interface variables have gone out of scope, they call `_Release` method of destroyed object which causes access violation. That's some risky business, though with some attention it is doable.

Classic Delphi components are not reference-counted, the concept of ownership is used instead. Each component has an owner whose responsibility is to free all the memory when it itself is destroyed. So each component has an owner, but it may also have a lot of pointers to another components, like when Toolbar has `ImageList` variable. If such components were refcounted, they would never be destroyed because of circular reference, so in order to break this circle you'd need 'weak' references as well which don't 'count'. They are here, too, but that's very recent feature of Delphi.

If there is some hierarchy in your objects, so you know that 'bigger' objects need all of 'smaller' ones to function, then use this good old approach, it's pretty simple and has very good implementation in Delphi, which is: you can make a code which will be leak-free no matter where exception could arise. There are all these little things like using `.Free` instead of `.Destroy`, because if exception happened in constructor, destructor is called automatically, and so on. Very clever solution in fact.

I'd use refcounted interfaces only if you don't know for how long some object is needed for you and there is no suitable 'owner' for it. I did it with scanned image which I saved to file in one thread, while converting to smaller image to show on screen on another thread. When all is done, image is no more needed in RAM and can be destroyed, but I have no idea which happens first. In this case using refcounting is best thing to do.